# How to load an R .rds file directly from the web?

Tags: r

I've tried the obvious

```
readRDS("https://www.example.com/myrds.RDS")
```

as well as

```
readRDS(url("https://www.example.com/myrds.RDS"))
```

But no luck so far

Comment: use download.file() first. any other function you know that works directly on URLs is using download.file() "under the hood"

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thanks for the knowledge. Are you sure though, someone else said I can 'stream' files? Or is that actually just downloading them to a temp file first, loading them into R (then possibly deleting the temp file)?